# rustc -L command not finding crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am just starting to use rust. I have installed rust with cargo and subsequently installed some packages, so that now `~/.cargo/registry/cache/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823` folder has many crates:

```
aho-corasick-0.5.3.crate   env_logger-0.4.3.crate    open-1.2.2.crate           regex-0.1.80.crate            textwrap-0.11.0.crate
aho-corasick-0.6.10.crate  gcc-0.3.55.crate          rand-0.3.23.crate          regex-0.2.11.crate            thread-id-2.0.0.crate
aho-corasick-0.7.3.crate   getrandom-0.1.2.crate     rand-0.4.6.crate           regex-1.1.6.crate             thread_local-0.2.7.crate
ansi_term-0.11.0.crate     hoedown-6.0.0.crate       rand-0.6.5.crate           regex-syntax-0.3.9.crate      thread_local-0.3.6.crate
atty-0.2.11.crate          itertools-0.5.10.crate    rand_chacha-0.1.1.crate    regex-syntax-0.5.6.crate      time-0.1.42.crate
autocfg-0.1.2.crate        kernel32-sys-0.2.2.crate  rand_core-0.3.1.crate      regex-syntax-0.6.6.crate      toml-0.2.1.crate
bitflags-0.5.0.crate       lazy_static-0.2.11.crate  rand_core-0.4.0.crate      rustc-serialize-0.3.24.crate  ucd-util-0.1.3.crate
bitflags-1.0.4.crate       lazy_static-1.3.0.crate   rand_hc-0.1.0.crate        rustc_version-0.1.7.crate     unicode-width-0.1.5.crate
cargo-script-0.2.8.crate   libc-0.2.51.crate         rand_isaac-0.1.1.crate     semver-0.1.20.crate           utf8-ranges-0.1.3.crate
cfg-if-0.1.7.crate         log-0.3.9.crate           rand_jitter-0.1.3.crate    semver-0.5.1.crate            utf8-ranges-1.0.2.crate
chan-0.1.23.crate          log-0.4.6.crate           rand_os-0.1.3.crate        semver-parser-0.6.2.crate     vec_map-0.8.1.crate
clap-2.33.0.crate          memchr-0.1.11.crate       rand_pcg-0.1.2.crate       shaman-0.1.0.crate            winapi-0.2.8.crate
either-1.5.2.crate         memchr-2.2.0.crate        rand_xorshift-0.1.1.crate  strsim-0.8.0.crate            winapi-build-0.1.1.crate
```

I now want to use rustc command with -L option for a simple source file from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html):

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;
fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$").unwrap();
    println!("Did our date match? {}", re.is_match("2014-01-01"));
}
```

However, this fails with following error:

```
$ rustc -L ~/.cargo/registry/cache/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823 hellomain.rs 
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `regex`
 --> hellomain.rs:4:1
  |
4 | extern crate regex;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
```

Why is rustc not finding crate and how can this be corrected? Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** same error occurs even if I specify the crate file name:

```
$ rustc -L ~/.cargo/registry/cache/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/regex-1.1.6.crate hellomain.rs
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `regex`
 --> hellomain.rs:4:1
  |
4 | extern crate regex;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
```

Comment: Can't check myself for now, but what if you pass here the path to crate itself (i.e. `~/.cargo/registry/cache/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/regex-{version}.crate`)?

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use `cargo`?

Comment: Cargo seem quite complex to a beginner like me.

Comment: @Cerberus : same errors occurs. I have added this in edit of my question above.

Comment: Cargo is much more simple then trying to get rustc parameters right. I'd strongly advise to try it, and if you encounter some problems not covered by the Book, ask a separate question.

Comment: The crate files are not libraries but a gzip archive of source code, in order to use it with -L, it is needed to uncompress it and build libraries.

Comment: @rnso have u gotten the answer? i want to use rustc instead of cargo also

Comment: No. Apparently `cargo` has to be used. However, I could not continue to use Rust and I have gone to try other languages.